# react-hook-form validation is not working in real devices

Tags: material-ui, react-hook-form

I am using react-form-hook and material-ui components to build a registration form. Issue here is, the validations that I use is working in desktop browser in mobile simulation mode but in real devices, no validation is working

```
 const restrictValue = (field: string, value: string, max: number) => {
    /* strip out everything but numbers [0-9] */
    const formattedValue = value.replace(/[^0-9]*/g, '');
    if (formattedValue.length > max) {
      setValue(field, formattedValue.slice(0, max));
    }
    return formattedValue;
  };

  return (
    <Box display="flex" flexDirection={'column'}>
      <Box display="flex" gap={2}>
        <FormInputText
          rules={{
            required: true,
            validate: {
              notNumber: (v: string) => {
                const parsedMonth = parseInt(v, 10);
                return !isNaN(parsedMonth);
              },
              minMax: (v: string) => {
                restrictValue('month', v, 2);
                const parsedMonth = parseInt(v, 10);
                return parsedMonth > 0 && parsedMonth <= 12;
              }
            }
          }}
          name="month"
          control={control}
          type="number"
          label={t('Month')}
          inputProps={{ maxLength: 2 }}
        />
```

restrictValue is not working in real devices. It lets user to enter any character.

tried with below option but my build is failing with below code change

```
inputProps={{ maxlength: 2, inputmode: 'numeric', pattern: '[0-9]*' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by passing inputMode= "numeric" to FormInputText component and also there was an issue with FormInputText component. I was using

```
  **I**nputProps={inputProps}
```

instead of

```
 inputProps={inputProps}
```

So final answer will be

```
return (
    <Box display="flex" flexDirection={'column'}>
      <Box display="flex" gap={2}>
        <FormInputText
          rules={{
            required: true,
            validate: {
              notNumber: (v: string) => {
                const parsedMonth = parseInt(v, 10);
                return !isNaN(parsedMonth);
              },
              minMax: (v: string) => {
                restrictValue('month', v, 2);
                const parsedMonth = parseInt(v, 10);
                return parsedMonth > 0 && parsedMonth <= 12;
              }
            }
          }}
          name="month"
          control={control}
          type="number"
          label={t('Month')}
          inputProps={{ maxLength: 2 }}
inputMode="numeric
        />
```

and in FormTextComponent:

```
 type={type}
          helperText={helperTextUtil ? helperTextUtil(error) : null}
          error={!!error}
          onChange={onChange}
          value={value}
          fullWidth
          label={label}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          inputProps={inputProps}
```